# VS Code debug not displaying icons for Step over

Tags: vscode-debugger

A video lesson using VS Code shows the debug tool being used with icons/buttons at the top of the VS Code display, which will step over, step in, etc. When I click the panel button to do a debug the "step over", etc buttons do not show up.

How do I activate that set of buttons to use with debug?